# In R , is there any avaiable funcation like IFERROR formula in EXCEL

Tags: r, tidyverse, ttr

In R , is there any available function like IFERROR formula in EXCEL ?
I want to calculate moving average using 4 nearest figures, but if the figures less than 4 in the group then using normal average.
Detail refer to below code, the IF_ERROR is just i wished function and can't work

```
library(tidyverse)
library(TTR)
test_data <- data.frame(category=c('a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b'),
             amount=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))

test_data %>% group_by(category) %>% mutate(avg_amount=IF_ERROR(TTR::runMedian(amount,4),
                                                                median(amount),
                                                                TTR::runMedian(amount,4))
```

Comment: See `?tryCatch`. Alternatively, you could use one of dplyr's windowing functions, then run a second `mutate` to catch any NAs left over.

Comment: @dash2  Thanks for your replay . Could you help to show the specific code ? Thanks

Comment: I'm not going to write a whole answer, but you want something like `mutate(avg_amount=tryCatch(TTR::runMedian(amount, 4), error = median(amount))`

Comment: @dash2 Whe I run the code , the error message show as below :    Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `avg_amount`.
i `avg_amount = tryCatch(TTR::runMedian(amount, 4), error = median(amount))`.
x attempt to apply non-function
i The error occurred in group 1: category = "a".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, input should only generate *errors* in exceptional circumstances. It can be computationally expensive to catch and handle errors where a simple `if` statement will suffice. The key here is realising that `runMedian` throws an error if the group size is less than 4. Remember we can check the group size inside `mutate` by using `n()`, so all you need do is:

```r
test_data %>% 
  group_by(category) %>% 
  mutate(avg_amount = if(n() > 3) TTR::runMedian(amount, 4) else median(amount))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#> # Groups:   category [2]
#>   category amount avg_amount
#>   <chr>     <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1 a             1        2  
#> 2 a             2        2  
#> 3 a             3        2  
#> 4 b             4       NA  
#> 5 b             5       NA  
#> 6 b             6       NA  
#> 7 b             7        5.5
#> 8 b             8        6.5
#> 9 b             9        7.5
```

Additionally, if you want to replace the NA values from the beginning of the running median, you could use `ifelse`:

```r
test_data %>% 
  group_by(category) %>% 
  mutate(avg_amount = if(n() > 3) TTR::runMedian(amount, 4) else median(amount),
         avg_amount = ifelse(is.na(avg_amount), median(amount), avg_amount))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#> # Groups:   category [2]
#>   category amount avg_amount
#>   <chr>     <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1 a             1        2  
#> 2 a             2        2  
#> 3 a             3        2  
#> 4 b             4        6.5
#> 5 b             5        6.5
#> 6 b             6        6.5
#> 7 b             7        5.5
#> 8 b             8        6.5
#> 9 b             9        7.5
```